# How do I set fixed height on TinyMCE in iOS Safari?

Tags: tinymce, mobile-safari

I'm having major problems getting TinyMCE having a fixed height on iPad. I have tried setting fixed heights on a container div, I have tried setting it via CSS, I have tried defining it in the init function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce is using an iframe to edit contents. Problem here is that on iPad/ios safari iframes do not get scrollbars. Instead safari will enlarge the iframe everytime when needed so that there is no need for scrollbars. This is the reson why setting a fixed height does not work on iOS-Safari.